# FCM push notifications not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Initializing the Firebase in admin.js:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

import serviceAccount from "./serviceAccount";

const options = {
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
};

admin.initializeApp(options);

export default admin;
```

Push notification service utilizing the admin.js:

```
import Firebase from './admin';

const response = await Firebase.messaging().sendToDevice(
  notifications.registrationTokens, // tokens for android and iOS devices
  notifications.payload // formatted as: notification: { title: '', body: ''}
);
```

There are two bugs as of now:

1) Push notification not showing up for iOS

2) When the app is running in the background, the push notification gets sent twice to the android device.

Comment: I am seeing the exact same thing.  For me, I've even made a new APN key, and uploaded it.  I had an app that had FCM earlier that was working.  I replaced the old APN key with the new one, and it still works.  However, the new app I'm working on does not work, using the same new APN key.